# Хорошие книги Java для настоящих чайников?

Tags: javascript, java, книги

Очень хотелось бы изучить этот язык программирования,но к сожалению я в этом дуб дубом. Посоветуйте что-нибудь, пусть даже за деньги, но чтобы дошло даже до кота естественно. На русском. Знаю HTML и CSS.

P.S : Объясните, как мне внедрить Яву и Яваскрипт в Html поподробней. Ну, в смысле скачанные коды.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что для вас лучше всего будет использование google.com и постоянные тренировки! Литературы дофигище в инете! Для улучшения логики стоит [This](http://informatics.mccme.ru/moodle/), так как на этом ресурсе много чего про базовые структуры (массивы, циклы)!